# machine code for backward conditional jump in 8086 microprocessor

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors, machine-code

How to construct the machine code for backward conditional jump (e.g. JNZ ) for 8086 microprocessor ?

```
 LOOP:  MOV DL, [BX]          (say this starts at 100C)
        ADD AX,DX             (this at 100E)
        INC BX                (1010)
        DEC CL                (1011)
        JNZ LOOP              (1013)
```

What will be the machine code of last line?
machine code for JNZ is 75 and here I want to jump by 9 bytes backward ( I think so).

Comment: Why don't you assemble it and find out?

Comment: I actually want to know the procedure of constructing machine code of this command. @Oliver Charlesworth

Comment: `nasm -f bin -o temp.bin foo.asm && ndisasm temp.bin`

Comment: @sohorabhossain: *I actually want to know the procedure of constructing machine code of this command.* Me too! There is no "3 byte"-`jnz` in the x86 instruction set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumps are based on the location **after** the jump instruction. Here you want to jump 9 bytes back and thus the encoding will be 75h,F7h